# Prevent content from resizing when text becomes bold

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, uwp

In my app, I have a tabbed layout (`PivotHeaderItem`) similar to the Windows Store app. Also similar to the Windows Store app, I have set the Selected tab's text to become bold. **However, when the text becomes bold, the item's width becomes slightly bigger, causing the other tabs to shift slightly; I'm wanting to prevent this from happening**.

I'm using my own `FormsPivot.HeaderTemplate`, which is here (in my custom `TabbedPageRenderer`):

```
private Windows.UI.Xaml.DataTemplate GetStyledHeaderTemplateDesktop(TabbedPage element)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();

    sb.Append("<DataTemplate xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation\"");
    sb.Append(" xmlns:x=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml\">");
    sb.Append("<TextBlock Text=\"{Binding Title}\" Padding=\"12 0 12 0\" FontFamily=\"{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}\" FontSize=\"16\" />");
    sb.Append("</DataTemplate>");

    return (Windows.UI.Xaml.DataTemplate)XamlReader.Load(sb.ToString());
}
```

As for how I set the text to Bold, in my UWP project's `App.xaml` file, I added the default style for the [`PivotHeaderItem`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299142.aspx), and then added the following code to the `VisualState`'s `Storyboard` for the `Selected`, `SelectedPressed`, and `SelectedHovered` states:

```
<ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
   Storyboard.TargetProperty="FontWeight" >
    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="SemiBold" />
</ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Breeze Liu - MSFT](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49912021/3183946)'s solution works, however I didn't want to specify a fixed width (forgot to mention that in the OP).

What I decided to do was to update the `HeaderItemTemplate` to include two `TextBlock` objects; one for the text that would change from bold/not bold, and another with the same text, but is always bold, as well as having an opacity of 0. I put them into a grid so the `TextBlock`s would sit on top of one another. Because the invisible (`Opacity = 0`) `TextBlock` underneath is always bold, the width will not change when the visible `TextBlock` becomes bold. A bit hacky, but it gets the job done...

```
private Windows.UI.Xaml.DataTemplate GetStyledHeaderTemplateDesktop(TabbedPage element)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();

    sb.Append("<DataTemplate xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation\"");
    sb.Append(" xmlns:x=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml\">");
    sb.Append("<TextBlock Text=\"{Binding Title}\" Padding=\"12 0 12 0\" FontFamily=\"{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}\" FontSize=\"16\" />");
    sb.Append("<TextBlock Text=\"{Binding Title}\" Padding=\"12 0 12 0\" FontFamily=\"{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}\" FontSize=\"16\" FontWeight=\"SemiBold\" Opacity=\"0\" />");
    sb.Append("</DataTemplate>");

    return (Windows.UI.Xaml.DataTemplate)XamlReader.Load(sb.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> However, when the text becomes bold, the item's width becomes slightly bigger, causing the other tabs to shift slightly; I'm wanting to prevent this from happening.

To avoid the item's width from resizing, you can give the `ContentPresenter` witch is in the default style for the `PivotHeaderItem` a fixed `Width` to include the header item content.

```
<ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter"  Width="96"
Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}"
FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}"
FontWeight="{TemplateBinding FontWeight}"
HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" 
OpticalMarginAlignment="TrimSideBearings" />
```

Similar principle, you can also give a border to contain the `ContentPresenter` then configure the border with a appropriate `Width`.

```
<Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="5" Width="96" >
    <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter"  
    Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
    ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
    FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}"
    FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}"
    FontWeight="{TemplateBinding FontWeight}"
    HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
    VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" 
    OpticalMarginAlignment="TrimSideBearings" />
</Border>
```